# How to resolve failing of some android device with webservices in CN1?

Tags: codenameone

I don't know why webservices is failing in some android device. I have a form on my project, that users have to enter a particular code, then this code will be checked on my server if the code exist, the user can use the application otherwise it wont go. Some users always complain that they do have problem with activation mostly on samsung galaxy phone or tablets. Pls do they need to give a permission before they can access this? Thanks

Comment: There is no need for permission for networking. I suggest looking at the server logs. If you can reproduce the issue on the device check the logs to see if there is an exception or an error. You can also use a network sniffer to look at the request going out from your phone to your server